# Unable to achieve right opacity with gradient Qml

Tags: qt, qml, gradient

I have a rectangle of white color whose top and bottom should be at 20% opacity, sort of a faded effect. I tried gradient property by using hexadecimal values, tried Qt.rgba() but there seems to be no effect. Is there something I am doing wrong or is there any other way?
A minimal code is as follows:

```
Rectangle{
   width: 400
   height: 400
   gradient: Gradient{
     GradientStop{ position : 0 ; color: "#33FFFFFF" } 
     GradientStop{ position : 0.4;color: "#FFFFFFFF"}
     GradientStop { position : 0.8 ; color: "#33FFFFFF"}
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your edit, I think your gradient is backwards. You want opacity of 0 in the middle and 100% at the top and bottom. And then you want to use that Rectangle as an overlay on top of your text. I would make it something like this:

```
Rectangle{
   width: 400
   height: 400
   gradient: Gradient{
     GradientStop{ position : 0.0; color: "#FFFFFFFF" } 
     GradientStop{ position : 0.2; color: "#33FFFFFF" } 
     GradientStop{ position : 0.4; color: "#00FFFFFF"}
     GradientStop{ position : 0.6; color: "#00FFFFFF"}
     GradientStop{ position : 0.8; color: "#33FFFFFF"}
     GradientStop{ position : 1.0; color: "#FFFFFFFF"}
   }
}
```